# Twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 breaks HTML5 Video Controls on Android

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented HTML5 video in my HTML page and using twitter bootstrap 2.3.2. The problem is when I browse the html page in android device, HTML5 Video is showing but video controls like play,pause,fullscreen are not shown. It runs smoothly on other mobile platforms and desktop  browsers. I have implemented the example and the problem can be tracked by browsing this URL in any android device : http://jsbin.com/AVuNEDa/1/edit

Thanks,
Gunjan

## Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" controls width="200" height="200"></video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screen shot from Android 4.2.2's stock browser using the above code:

[image: Broken video controls caused by Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2]

Screen shot from Android 4.2.2's stock browser using the above code, but without Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2:

[image: Normal video controls]

Comment: please add the relevant part of the code with the question.

Comment: I have a cause, but not a solution. The cause is lines [97](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/less/forms.less#L97) and [151](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/less/forms.less#L151) of "forms.less".

Answer (score 1):

There is discussion about this issue on the [bootstrap github issues](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7104) page which includes a possible solution. The suggestion is that you add the following code to a CSS file loaded after bootstrap:

```
input[type="button"]{cursor:default;-webkit-appearance:media-play-button}
input[type="button"]{cursor:default}
input{width:auto}
input[type="button"]{width:50px}

html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{cursor:pointer;-webkit-appearance:button}
html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"],input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{cursor:pointer}
html input,textarea,.uneditable-input{width:206px}
html input[type="button"],input[type="radio"],input[type="checkbox"]{width:auto}
```

Comment: I tested this on Android 4.2.2's stock browser. I used the code shown in the question and added the suggested CSS after Twitter Bootstrap. It made the buttons return to their normal size, but, for whatever reason, there was a pause button where the full screen button should be. It still behaved like the full screen button, though. This could certainly confuse users, though, so, unfortunately, this isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: It might be a starting point though. Why not create a version of the fiddle with the updated code and we could go from there.

Comment: Good work. Can't look just now but will try to get to it soon.

Comment: OK. I've been testing on a physical device, but wanted to be sure these issues (the original issue and the one I mentioned with the pause button) were both reproducible in the Android emulator. I tested this with Android 4.1.2, 4.2.2, 4.3, and 4.4.2 and both issues were, in fact, reproducible in all of those versions except for 4.4.2. In 4.4.2, the video player looks different and is unaffected by Bootstrap's CSS. It is also unaffected by the suggested CSS.

Comment: You were right about this CSS being a good starting point. I found a solution that works for my particular case since my website doesn't have any `<input type="button">` elements. See my answer. Since you pointed me in the right direction, I'll award you the bounty. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers dude! I've tried for a lot of bounties and never got one so that totally made my day. You know you can mark your own answer as correct?

Comment: No problem! I would mark my answer as correct, but I wasn't the one to ask the question :)

Comment: Ah of course! Hand't twigged. Have an upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

If your website doesn't have any `<input type="button">` elements, I believe it's safe to just add this somewhere after the Bootstrap 2.3.2 CSS:

```
input[type="button"] {
    width: 48px;
}
```

If your site uses only `<input type="submit">`, `<button type="button">`, or `<button type="submit">`, the above CSS won't affect any of these three kinds of elements. You probably shouldn't be using `<input type="button">` or `<input type="submit">` anyway because, as [the Bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) points out (and this applies to Bootstrap 2.3.2 as well):

> As a best practice, **we highly recommend using the `<button>` element
>   whenever possible** to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.
>
> Among other things, there's [a Firefox
>   bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697451) that
>   prevents us from setting the `line-height` of `<input>`-based buttons,
>   causing them to not exactly match the height of other buttons on
>   Firefox.